# How to replace Over clause in sql version 4.9.5

Tags: php, sql, database

I am trying to run a query to find the count and percentage of artisan based on gender. The query is running absolutely fine on the SQL server 8. But not on my live server which is 4.9.5.
The below is my query.

```
SELECT industry
       , count(*) as cnt
       , (count(*)*100.0/sum(count(*))over()) as perc 
FROM `artisan_work` 
GROUP BY industry 
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Comment: What database?  4.9.5 of *what*?  That doesn't ring a bell for any database.

Comment: Please share more details. How is the given question even related to PHP?

Comment: I was finding the percentage of users via this query and then displaying the perc in the HTML table as a percentage.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In any database, you should be able to use:

```
SELECT aw.industry, count(*) as cnt,
       count(*) * 100.0 / tot.cnt as perc 
FROM artisan_work aw cross join
     (SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM artisan_work) tot
GROUP BY aw.industry 
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Comment: The overall query is working fine but the percentage is showing 100% for all the cases can you help me in that

Comment: @HusnainYusufi . . . Can you provide some example data in a DB Fiddle?

Comment: Below is the code with query hope you get this
 $ret=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT industry
       , count(*) as cnt
       , ((select count(*) from artisan_work b where a.industry=b.industry)*100.0/count(*)) as perc 
FROM artisan_work  a
GROUP BY industry 
ORDER BY cnt DESC  ");
       $cnt=1;
       $sum=0;
       while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($ret)) {
?>
        
         <td><?php echo $cnt;?>.</td>
         <td><?php echo ucfirst($row['industry']);?></td>
         <td><?php echo $row['cnt'];?></td>
         <td><?php echo round($row['perc'], 1); ?> &percnt;</td>

Comment: Now this query shows 100% for every detail.  can you fix this

Comment: The query in your comment is not the query in this answer.

Comment: I have tried the below query let me try this one my bad

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT industry
       , count(*) as cnt
       , (count(*)*100.0/(select count(*) from artisan_work )) as perc 
FROM artisan_work  a
GROUP BY industry 
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Comment: @HusnainYusufi . . . I don't think this is equivalent to the query in your question.

Comment: The overall query is working fine but the percentage is showing 100% for all the cases can you help me in that

Comment: My previous answer was wrong one Sorry for that. I have revised my answer. It should work now.